# Blackberry Pre-Fetch Page

Tags: blackberry

we would like to pre-fetch a remote page (given a URL) while the user is reading the first page. This is for performance reasons.

The problem is that many Blackberry browser versions don't support iFrames or Object tags, and setting up a proxy to ajax inject the remote page's HTML into a hidden DIV seems really hackish and sketchy.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say Ajax is hackish. It's the main thing going for web 2.0. Loads of sites use it, you just need to make sure its locked down so that its secure and cannot be hacked.

Just brainstorming for an alternative... when that slow data is loaded can you store it in the database? Perhaps use ajax to query every x seconds to see when the data is available... when it is reload the entire page with the new data inserted. This would avoid inserting into a div, but does not avoid the ajax.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the response....  I didn't mean Ajax itself is hackish, but in this case, it seems to me that setting up a proxy and grabbing websites (that are not under our domain or control) results in unpredictable behavior (images may or may not be relatively linked, web server may or may not block a request of this type, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by writing an application using the BrowserField. Fetch and display the first page, then fetch the data to the second page and wait for the user action to display it.

Answer (score 0):

didn't use a pre-fetch.  no great ultra cross-compatible solution.